# Efficient Intersection of pandas dataframe with remote mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I have a python pandas dataframe on my local machine, and have access to a remote mongodb server that has additional data that I can query via pymongo.

If my local dataframe is large, say 40k rows with 3 columns in each row, what's the most efficient way to check for the intersection of my local dataframe's features and a remote collection containing millions of documents?

I'm looking for general advice here.  I thought I could just take a distinct list of values from each of the 3 features, and use each of these in an $or find statement, but if I have 90k distinct values for one of the 3 features it seems like a bad idea.

So any opinion would be very welcome.  I don't have access to insert my local dataframe into the remote server, I only have select/find access.

thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already explained that you won't be able to insert data. So only thing is possible is first take the unique values to a list.`df['column_name'].unique()`. Then you can use the `$in` operator in `.find()` method and pass your list as a parameter. If it takes time or it is too much. Then break your list in equal chunks, I mean list of list `[[id1, id2, id3], [id4, id5, id6] ... ]` and do a for loop `for sub-list in list: db.xyz.find({'key':{'$in': sublist}}, {'_id': 1})` and use the sub list as parameter in `$in` operator. Then for each iteration if the value exist in the db it will return the `_id` and we can easily store that in a empty list and append it and we will be able to get all the id's in such cases where the value exist in the collection.

So it's just the way I would do. Not necessarily the best possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I tried using the distinct values from each feature and use those in an $in, in order to extract a subset to a dataframe I could then use pandas intersect to find the matching rows - what I didn't consider was that the distinct set of values from one feature was effectively enough to query for every document in the remote collection.  So in the end i just used an $and for each of the 3 features and just hammered the mongodb server with a single query per row.  It did work, I just didn't like doing it, as it just didn't feel like a good way to do it.  But thanks again!